# To show that 2 roots of $(x-a)^3$ + $(x-b)^3$ +$(x-c)^3 = 0 $ are complex

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am afraid that this question might be marked duplicate, but I simply had to ask if there is a way to show that the equation $(x-a)^3$ + $(x-b)^3$ +$(x-c)^3 = 0$ has only 1 real root? One of my teachers in high school posed the problem, and here's the twist, asked for a solution that does **NOT** invoke Rolle's theorem. He gave a hint that we could use the graph of said equation, but I don't see how that helps. I tried using Descartes' rules and Vieta's formulae, but they don't seem to lead anywhere. Thanks for helping!

**EDIT:**
After some insights from gracious responders,I see that my question boils down to this:Can we construct some artfully watertight piece of argument which shows that an increasing function has one and only one real root?

Comment: It's an increasing function....

Comment: Suppose $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real. $(x-a)^3+(x-b)^3+(x-c)^3$ is straightly increasing, so its graph cuts the $x$-axis once only.

Comment: Thanks for helping. But can we show that it cuts the x-axis only once?By algebra.I can see that it follows the graph of x^3,But that is not a proof.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments already suggest, calculate $f'(x)$,

$$f'(x)=3\left((x-a)^2+(x-b)^2+(x-c)^2\right)$$

Can you state something about $f'(x)$ that will help you determine it has only one root?

Comment: This equation forces x=a=b=c, at the maxima or minima betwwen three roots,thus causing degeneracy, when we don't have any assumption regarding a,b,c except they are reals.

Comment: None of the comments suggested differentiating $f$.

Comment: @abhibrataganguly, It isn't necessary that a function has a maxima or a minima.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, I am just proving it is an increasing function. (The comments were suggesting that). This seems like the easiest way.

Comment: It is easy to visualize.I guess that's why he forbid Rolle's theorem.

Comment: @abhibrataganguly, Or you can just visualise this as a sum of $3$ increasing functions ($x_a^3+x_b^3+x_c^3$), this is another way to prove it is increasing.

Comment: I could do that as well. So my question boils down to this, can I show that an increasing function has only one real root? It is easy to see that , but can I Prove it?

Comment: @abhibrataganguly, I am too a high school student so I am not so much into proofs.

Comment: Oh. I just wanted a watertight general demonstration, I guess. This is quite easy to visualize, but tricky to show.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $f(x)$ has $r$ real roots, then $f'(x)$ will have atleast $r-1$ real roots.

Then you just have to prove that $f'(x)$ has **no** real roots.

Comment: @prog_SAHIL Please read my statement again. I said **if** $f(x)$ **has** $r$ real roots.

Comment: I misread. Deleted.

Comment: How do I  proceed?

Comment: @abhibrataganguly Can you prove $f'(x)$ has no real roots?

Comment: Yup, x=a=b=c,which can't be allowed as I said in an earlier response.But is there a non-calculus way of showing the idea?

Comment: @abhibrataganguly [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371717/relation-between-real-roots-of-a-polynomial-and-real-roots-of-its-derivative/1371781#1371781) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the equation
$$3x^3-3x^2(a+b+c)+3x(a^2+b^2+c^2)-(a^3+b^3+c^3)=0$$
Then defining
$$f(x)=3x^3-3x^2(a+b+c)+3x(a^2+b^2+c^2)-(a^3+b^3+c^3)$$ and use Calculus.

Comment: I think there are too many cases to be dealt with here if you want to use Descartes's Rule of Signs.  The only coefficient that we know the sign is the coefficient of $x$.

Comment: Thank you for your hint,just corrected.

Comment: Without calculus?

Comment: Then you can use laws of Cardano's formula about the discriminant.

Comment: Would you **please** write the discriminant of your cubic and add it in your answer ?