# If $f$ is a polynomial in one variable with real coefficients which has all its roots real, then its derivative $f'$ has all its roots real

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, polynomials

Is  the following statement  true/false ?

> If  $f$ is  a polynomial in one variable  with real coefficients which  has  all its roots real, then  its derivative  $f'$ has all its roots real as  well

My attempt  : I think  this  statement is false. Take $f(x) =  \frac{1}{3} x^3 + x$ and now $f'(x) = x^2 + 1  $ , $x^2+ 1=0 $ implies  $x= i,-i$  which does not belong to $\mathbb{R}$,   so given the above question statement is false

Edits  :another  counter example   $f(x) = x+1$ , but $f'(x) =1$   has  no root in $\mathbb{R}$

Is  its  true ?

Comment: The roots of $f(x) = \frac{1}{3} x^3+x$ are not real.

Comment: Your given $f$ has zeroes $x=0,\pm\sqrt 3 i$, so does not satisfy the assumption.

Comment: Your counter-example doesn't work since the statement says'...a polynomial with real coefficients which has ALL its real roots,....' Your $f$ only has one real root.

Comment: Unfortunately $f(x)$ do not have all its roots real.  $i\sqrt 3$ and $-i\sqrt 3$ are two of its roots.

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371717/relation-between-real-roots-of-a-polynomial-and-real-roots-of-its-derivative

Comment: i have edits  a  new  counter example @KevinCarlson

Comment: In fact $1$ does have all its roots in $\mathbb R$ in the intended sense: if $x$ is a root of $1$, then $x\in\mathbb R$. An implication with a false premise is always true.

Comment: Second example:  It doesn't have any roots in R but it doesn't have any roots *not* in R either.  For "all its roots real" to be false it not enough to say "none of its roots are real".  You have to say "some of its roots are not real".  And you can't say that if there are no roots at all.

Comment: okss @fleablood   u  mean $ f(x) =1$  have  no real   or complex roots   so  i  can   not  take this  example

Comment: @jasmine (off topic) I was checking some of your past questions (for instance see the last 3 in the _Related list of questions_ in the RHS), as you can notice, the title of your questions is not very _descriptive_, would you mind on writting a more descriptive title from now on?

Comment: okss  thanks @Isabellatrix

Comment: @jasmine Thank you :)

Comment: This is a particular case of [Gauss-Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

Note that the only irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{R}$ are quadratic and linear, that is, every polynomial can be broken down into a product of linear or quadratic polynomials. So it is enough to analyze the problem for the case of polynomials of grade 1 and 2. It is easy to see that when the polynomial has grade 1 there is nothing to do. Let's analyze the case of grade 2.

Let $f(x) = ax^{2} +bx+c$ so $f^{\prime}(x) = 2ax +b$. Now, if $f^{\prime}(x)$ have a complex root then $x=- \frac{b}{2a} \in \mathbb{C}$ which implity that $x= - \frac{b}{2a} \pm \frac{\sqrt{b^{2}-4ac} }{2a} \in \mathbb{C}$, i. e., $f(x)$ have a complex root.

Comment: Why does the fact that a polynomial can be written as a product of linear or quadratic polynomials imply that it suffices to show that $f'$ has real roots for $f$ of degree $1$ or $2$?

Answer (score 0):

Whether f'(X) will have real roots or not depend on the number of times the differentiable function changes its direction FROM INCREASING TO DECREASING OR FROM DECREASING TO INCREASING.
$$let\,\,f(x)=x^3-x $$
$$f(x)=0 at x=0,1,-1 $$
f(x) is continuous hence twice will change its direction to become zero once between -1 and 0 and another time between 0 and 1.
$$f'(x)=3x^2-1=0\,\,at \,\,x=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$
Whereas if you consider a function monotonically increasing or decreasing e.g $f(x)=x^3+x + 1 $ is increasing hence even though f(x) = 0 for one of the real value of x but f'(x) will have complex roots only.
With exception as in case of function of form f(x)=$x^n$ for $n\in N$.

Answer (score 0):

The roots of f’(x) always lie in the convex hull of the roots of f(x). Hence if f(x) has only real roots, the convex hull is a subset of the real line which in turn implies that the roots of f’(x) are also real.